# Prioritize section of IF statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement

I've got an IF statement that validates data.

Basically looks like this:

```
Dim s As String = Nothing

If s Is Nothing Or s.Length = 0 Then
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value")
End If

Console.Read()
```

I'd like to check to see if it's nothing first because if I write it this way, it throws a NullReferenceException.

I've thought of re-writing it like this:

```
If s Is Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value")
ElseIf s.Length = 0 Then
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value")
End If
```

But if I do this I've got the same error message twice and I believe it's less clear what my intent is.

I've also tried throwing parenthesis around the s Is Nothing clause, but it doesn't work.

Is there an elegant what to test if the object is nothing and then test a property of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.NET 2.0 introduced the [`OrElse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx) keyword to do short-circuiting.  What this means is that it will not evaluate the right-side of the `OrElse` if the left side is true.  Other than that, it works exactly like `Or`.

The `And` equivalent is [`AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx), which will not evaluate the right side if the left side is false.

```
Dim s As String = Nothing

If s Is Nothing OrElse s.Length = 0 Then
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value")
End If

Console.Read()
```

should do what you want.

Comment: True. However, this does not explain why his second code also throws a NullReference exception. In the ignorance of this keyword, his second code should be a valid workaround.

Comment: @Daniel Daranas:  Hmm, that is true.  I guess I just can't wrap my head around Is Nothing returning a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Oops I think I misunderstood what the OP said. He says he "gets the same error message twice", probably refering to "Please enter a value".

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, what I meant was that I get the NullReference only in the first example. In the second example I have to include the error message ("Please enter a value") twice, hence violating DRY.

Comment: @Nathan I understood, after a second reading. However, you could easily manage that by setting a boolean variable "isInputInvalid" to true and then check it and show the message if it is true.

Comment: @Daniel Daranas: You're right but OrElse is even better/more simple ;)

Comment: Note that the C# || (or) and && (and) operators have always short-circuited, so they are equivalent to OrElse and AndElse in VB.Net. VB.Net 2008 also has an If operator that can be used for short-circuiting, and works in a similar way to the C# ?: operator.

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
{
//do work
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of that one.  Good catch.

Comment: yeah it is a nice method that makes the code look cleaner...and of course is only going to work for string....

Comment: @CSharpAtl: True, but it expresses the intent more clearly, and checks if it's String.Empty to boot.

Comment: Thanks, this works but my example was a simplification of a more complex object.

Comment: Yeah I threw this in because it works for your specific example.....but will not work on a generic object sense...